# CSS: change padding when content reaches max width

Tags: css

Is there any way to change (or remove) padding on an element when it is wider than maximum width.

Example:

```
<div class="button">OK!</div>
<div class="button">Im too wide for my own good!</div>
```

http://codepen.io/Krillko/pen/VveaZp

In the first div, I want padding, but not in the second one, depending on parent.

Comment: Do not use padding. Use width and height with line-height for vertical aligning instead. What are you trying to achieve?!

Comment: No...CSS can't detect width etc to apply padding.

Comment: @user3275665  It's horizontal padding I'm after. I cant manually set width since it's hundreds of buttons in 18 languages.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done by using jquery like the following:

```
var width_holder = $(".holder").width();
var width_button = $(".button").width();
if (width_holder < width_button) {
  $(".button").css("padding", "0");
}
```

(not tested, but the logic should be clear :) )

Comment: well, i think there is no way of doing this without any logic, because html and css is simply not clever enough.... sometimes you have to use other technologies to achieve you "design"-goals... and if you don't want to, you have to adjust your design and make a compromise... in this case, you could simply remove the `white-space: nowrap;`